# Enabling CardEmulation on Android ICS with NFC_EXTRAS

Tags: android, payment, nfc

I need help with NFC and Android.

After making a lot of research to enable the emulation of a Mifare 4K on Android, I've found that the only patch that exists was made for 2.3.4. Here in StackOverFlow, NFCGuy told us since API 14 of Android it's not neccesary patch the ROM, so we can turn on card emulation using the hidden Nfc_extras package.

I've compiled an APK using NFC_EXTRAS with reflection, and added my signature and package to the nfcee_access.xml.

After I set cardEmulationRoute to ON_WHEN_SCREEN_ON, I get an output in logcat telling me that NFCEE is ON and NFC_CC is ON, but when I get my Nexus S close to a ACR122 it does not detect the Emulated Mifare 4K that 2.3.4 patch makers could get. I can get an unrecognized Smart Card (I suppose that it's the SE acting like a smartcard) but i need to use the emulated Mifare.

**Do I need to modify lib-nfc as it was modify in 2.3.4 patch to get that applet working (Mifare Manager)? Or with my app accesing that package should be enought?**

I'm downloading the android source to port the 2.3.4 patch to 4.1, but looking at the diff they've posted, there is only a difference with 4.1 on lib-nfc library. (A define commented, used for card emulation in theory)

Maybe it's not necesary to recompile a modified ROM and I'm missing a small step to get the emulated Mifare 4k.

Thanks for your help to all people here in StackOverFlow

Regards

```
    private void getSecureElement(){
    try{
        //Obtenemos la clase NFCAdapterExtras
        Class nfcExtrasClazz = Class.forName("com.android.nfc_extras.NfcAdapterExtras");

        if (nfcExtrasClazz == null){
            Log.w("EnableCardEmu", "No existe la clase Extras");
            return;
        }

        Log.w("EnableCardEmu", "Existe la clase");

        //Obtenemos el método "get" de dicha clase
        Method getMethod = nfcExtrasClazz.getMethod("get", Class.forName("android.nfc.NfcAdapter"));

        if (getMethod == null) {
            Log.w("EnableCardEmu", "No existe el método");
        } else {
            Log.w("EnableCardEmu", "Existe el método");
            //Obtenemos el manager del componente NFC del dispositivo
            NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

            if (adapter == null)
                Log.w("EnableCardEmu", "Adapter es null");
            else {
                //Instancia del SecureElement
                Log.w("EnableCardEmu", "Adapter NO es null");
                nfcExtras = getMethod.invoke(null, adapter);

                Method getEEMethod = nfcExtras.getClass().getMethod("getEmbeddedExecutionEnvironment", 
                        (Class[]) null);
                embebbed = getEEMethod.invoke(nfcExtras , (Object[]) null);
            }
        }
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ee){
        Log.w("EnableCardEmu", ee.getTargetException());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.w("EnableCardEmu", e.getClass().getName() + " / " + e.getMessage());
        StackTraceElement[] a = e.getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement aa : a){
            Log.w("EnableCardEmu", aa.toString());
        }
    } 
}

    private void deactivateCardEmulation(){
    try{
        Class clss = Class.forName("com.android.nfc_extras.NfcAdapterExtras");
        Class[] cs = clss.getDeclaredClasses();
        /*          
        for (Class cc : cs){
            Log.w("EnableCardEmu", cc.getName();)
        }*/

        //Class route = Class.forName("com.android.nfc_extras.NfcAdapterExtras$CardEmulationRoute");
        Constructor c = cs[0].getConstructor(Integer.TYPE, Class.forName("com.android.nfc_extras.NfcExecutionEnvironment"));
        Object routeOn = c.newInstance(1, null);

        Class cls = nfcExtras.getClass();           
        Method mtd = cls.getMethod("setCardEmulationRoute", cs[0]);
        mtd.invoke(nfcExtras, routeOn);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ee){
        Log.w("EnableCardEmu", ee.getTargetException());
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.w("EnableCardEmu", e.getClass().getName() + " / " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

    private void activateCardEmulation(){
    try{

        Class clss = Class.forName("com.android.nfc_extras.NfcAdapterExtras");
        Class[] cs = clss.getDeclaredClasses();
        /*          
        for (Class cc : cs){
            Log.w("EnableCardEmu", cc.getName();)
        }*/

        //Class route = Class.forName("com.android.nfc_extras.NfcAdapterExtras$CardEmulationRoute");
        Constructor c = cs[0].getConstructor(Integer.TYPE, Class.forName("com.android.nfc_extras.NfcExecutionEnvironment"));
        Object routeOn = c.newInstance(2, embebbed);

        Class cls = nfcExtras.getClass();           
        Method mtd = cls.getMethod("setCardEmulationRoute", cs[0]);
        mtd.invoke(nfcExtras, routeOn);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ee){
        Log.w("EnableCardEmu", ee.getTargetException());
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.w("EnableCardEmu", e.getClass().getName() + " / " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some source code? That would be helpful.

Comment: I've attached the three methods that I use to get NfcAdapterExtras instance, and the other two methods to activate and deactivate. Thanks!

Comment: Another tip:

Logcat tells me that my app has gained explicit access to NFCEE because of my modified nfcee_access.xml so thats OK, I can get the instance of NfcAdapterExtras and setCardEmulationRoute OK, the only thing I need is the emulated Mifare

Comment: Hi @noni, I am using similar code with Nexus S (PN544 chip) for Mifare emulation. You might need some additional Mifare commands (depending on the reader type) for successful emulation. Can you show us the code-blocks where you start responding to the reader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem could be in `Object routeOn = c.newInstance(2, embebbed)`. It looks like this object is of the wrong type (I am not an expert on reading reflection code, though).

This is how I do it, without reflection, and it works fine (both an ISO 14443-4A card and a MIFARE Classic card are emulated by the device simultaneously):

```
Context mContext; // initialize this
NfcAdapterExtras mAdapterExtras =
  NfcAdapterExtras.get(NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(mContext));
NfcExecutionEnvironment mEe = mAdapterExtras.getEmbeddedExecutionEnvironment();
mAdapterExtras.setCardEmulationRoute(
  new CardEmulationRoute(CardEmulationRoute.ROUTE_ON_WHEN_SCREEN_ON, mEe));
```

No need to modify libnfc-nxp for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my code does the same thing.

CardEmulationRoute.ROUTE_ON_WHEN_SCREEN_ON is an int with value 2 (Thats because I've harcoded the number 2 in the new Instance method), and "embebbed" is the instance obtained from getEmbebbedExecutionEnvironment().

But one important thing you say is that my Nexus should emulate 2 smartcards. Probably my issue is there, i'm using the ACR22 with a propietary .Net application, so maybe is a chance that im not reading the second smartcard. The strange thing is that my other Galaxy S3 doesnt detect the Nexus S (In emulation mode) neither

Comment: But is `routeOn` of the desired type? I see no reference to class `CardEmulationRoute` in your code (except in a line that is commented out). When I say that it emulates both cards, I mean that both are emulated by a single target, so you will not see 2 cards (see e.g. http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/130830.pdf for details how to detect and select it). Android devices are configured such that they will not detect each other in card emulation mode, but only as peer-to-peer target for Android Beam.

Comment: Yes, is desired type. Because CardEmulationRoute is an innerclass, class.forname didnt find it calling it by its name, so I ve used getDeclaredClasses into NfcAdapterExtras to get a Class instance of the inner. Apart of this i am not getting a ClassCastException so I am generating a correct instance of CardEmulationRoute. The tip between Android phones is great, didnt know that, thanks. I will try with ACR and another reading soft. Thanks for your help

Comment: It is probably that im not picking the correct APDU. The pdf file that you have attached is probably the solution I need. I will try that, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your code should be properly enabling card emulation mode.  I was also attempting the same thing and encountered a similar problem, where I could not detect the phone with my MIFARE compatible RFID reader.

What turned out to be the cause was that the phone I was working with had NFC support but did not have an embedded secure element installed.  The secure element resided on the SIM card instead and the built-in NFC support in ICS 4.0.3 was not able to locate and use that secure element.

This same brand/model of phone has an embedded secure element when sold through some cell providers but not through my provider.

I got my first hint that this was the cause when I attempted to do an "open" on my instance of the NfcExecutionEnvironment and the following output showed up in my logcat:

```
D/NFC JNI (  911): phLibNfc_SE_GetSecureElementList()
D/NFC JNI (  911): 
D/NFC JNI (  911): > Number of Secure Element(s) : 0
E/NFC JNI (  911): phLibNfc_SE_GetSecureElementList(): No SMX detected
```

Comment: I've tested my code with a Nexus S, and logcat did not return that message, It only said SMX EE enabled or something like that.
My problem was that my reader (ACR122U) was selecting another type of card so the phone did not returned the simulated Mifare